# Swift: Could not find an overload for || that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift, boolean-expression

```
if(inputField == nil || numbersLabel == nil || inputField!.text! <  4 || numbersLabel!.text! <  4)
```

when i'm going to run the app its showing that could not find an overload for  this `||` supplied arguments.

Comment: Please paste the full error and bit more code context to know the type of your variables `inputField` and `numbersLabel`.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrea points out, the problem is you are comparing a string (`text`) to an integer (`4`), and you need to convert `text` into an int.

But there’s another optimization that can be made as well – you are checking `inputField` is non-nil, and then force-unwrapping it.  But this isn’t necessary – `<` is defined for optionals as “`nil` is less than everything else except another `nil`, otherwise compare non-`nil` values”.  So instead of `x == nil || x! < 4` you can write just `x < 4`.

So you can write your `if` statement as:

```
// Swift 1.2:
if inputField?.text?.toInt() < 4 || numbersLabel?.text?.toInt() < 4 {

// Swift 2.0:
if inputField?.text.flatMap({Int($0)}) < 4 || numbersLabel?.text.flatMap({Int($0)}) < 4 {
```

Comment: Thank You for posting about flatMap never heard about it but already fallen in love

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably here:

```
inputField!.text! <  4
```

It is expeting to have an operator that confront a `String` vs `Int` and there isn't. You must convert one of the values on the right or left side to match the type.

Try this:

```
inputField!.text!.toInt() <  4
```

or

```
Int(inputField!.text!) <  4
```